# TS - Cannot call a public method within super() from the children

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I've got two classes. 
One is parent Model class. Another is its children, so that:

```
import { IModel } from '../shared'

export default class DataModel implements IModel {

  private data: {[key: string]: any} = {}

  public constructor(data: {[key: string]: any}) {
    this.data = data
  }

  // ... other methods

  public forRequest = (params?: {[key: string]: any}): object => {
    return {
      ...this.data,
      ...params
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
import { IModel } from '../shared'
import DataModel from './_'

export default class LoginModel extends DataModel implements IModel {

  constructor() {
    super({
      email: 'info@email.com',
      password: 'test1234'
    })
  }

  public forRequest = (): object => {
    return super.forRequest({
      sso: true
    })
  }
}
```

and:

```
export interface IModel {
  forRequest(params?: {[key: string]: any}): object
  ...
}
```

Following the https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html and example with animals, I would like to call my `forRequest()` method, passing parameters to the parent class.

However, when I am calling `super.forRequest(...)` I am getting error: **Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.ts(2340)** .

(I have no problem to overload *forRequest()* method in parent class if this could be a solution, if necessary but not sure if this is such a good idea). (in *IModel* I tried in both ways, with params and without)

I am wondering what is different here than on the example from TS site, and why the code does not work.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is with the way you declare your `forRequest` function.

You're assigning a function as the value of the `forRequest` property as opposed to assigning it to the prototype.

You only have access to `super` in the child methods.

You should have access if you did this instead.

```
class DataModel {

  private data: {[key: string]: any} = {}

  public constructor(data: {[key: string]: any}) {
    this.data = data
  }

  // ... other methods

  public forRequest(params?: {[key: string]: any}): object {
    return {
      ...this.data,
      ...params
    }
  }
}

class LoginModel extends DataModel {

  constructor() {
    super({
      email: 'info@email.com',
      password: 'test1234'
    })
  }

  public forRequest(): object {
    return super.forRequest({
      sso: true
    })
  }
}
```

See what it compiles to [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20DataModel%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20private%20data%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20constructor(data%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.data%20%3D%20data%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20...%20other%20methods%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20forRequest(params%3F%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%7D)%3A%20object%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...this.data%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...params%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20LoginModel%20extends%20DataModel%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20email%3A%20'info%40email.com'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20password%3A%20'test1234'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20public%20forRequest()%3A%20object%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20super.forRequest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20sso%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thank you! You are right. It is very important difference to mention regarding use cases of arrow functions and 'normal' assignment. Totally forgot about it!